# Using GetUserName for multiple Windows versions and 32/64

Tags: delphi, winapi

Is it possible to use the Win API function `GetUserName` for Windows XP through Windows 8? For both 32 and 64 bit?

```
function getUserName: String;
var
  BufSize: DWord;
  Buffer: PWideChar;
begin
 BufSize:= 1024;
 Buffer:= AllocMem(BufSize);
 try
  if GetUserName(Buffer, BufSize) then
      SetString(result, Buffer, BufSize)
 else
  RaiseLastOSError;
 finally
  FreeMem(Buffer);
 end;
end;
```

thanx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx  function is available from Windows 2000 through to current day, so yes.

Comment: Are you really asking a Yes/No question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.  `GetUserName()` is available on all Windows versions.

However, the code you showed will only compile on Delphi 2009 and later, since you are passing a `PWideChar` to `GetUserName()` and `SetString()`, which only works if `GetUserName()` maps to `GetUserNameW()` and `String` maps to `UnicodeString`.  If you need the code to compile on earlier Delphi versions, use `PChar` instead of `PWideChar`, to match whatever mapping `GetUserName()` and `String` are actually using, eg:

```
function getUserName: String;
const
  UNLEN = 256;
var
  BufSize: DWord;
  Buffer: PChar;
begin
  BufSize := UNLEN + 1;
  Buffer := StrAlloc(BufSize);
  try
    if Windows.GetUserName(Buffer, BufSize) then
      SetString(Result, Buffer, BufSize-1)
    else
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    StrDispose(Buffer);
  end;
end;
```

Which can then be simplified to this:

```
function getUserName: String;
const
  UNLEN = 256;
var
  BufSize: DWord;
  Buffer: array[0..UNLEN] of Char;
begin
  BufSize := Length(Buffer);
  if Windows.GetUserName(Buffer, BufSize) then
    SetString(Result, Buffer, BufSize-1)
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Or this:

```
function getUserName: String;
const
  UNLEN = 256;
var
  BufSize: DWord;
begin
  BufSize := UNLEN + 1;
  SetLength(Result, BufSize);
  if Windows.GetUserName(PChar(Result), BufSize) then
    SetLength(Result, BufSize-1)
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: Earlier Delphi versions don't understand `WinApi.Windows`, also maximum username length is defined as UNLEN in lmcons.h (JwaLmCons.pas) with value 256 so that can be used for buffer size.

Comment: Using `UNLEN` constant is not future-compatible. Not that there is a lot of chances to username grow beyond 256 characters, but still. So, i'd prefer different pattern to work with Win32 API string functions. 1) call `GetUserName` with `nil` buffer and zero as buffer length. 2) get not-enough-buffer-memory error (signaled slightly different across different API functions) and the exact required length. 3) allocate proper memory and then fetch the real data by calling `GetUserData` again. 4) no need in second call to `SetLength` as we already sized buffer properly beforehand